# Why does a preprocessor directive affect my C++ vector?

Tags: c++, vector, c-preprocessor

I have a class with a block of members that are wrapped in a preprocessor directive:

```
class MyClass
{

... 

#ifdef MyConditionalCompilation

MyObject myObject;
std::string myString;
uint _myInt;

#endif

...

}
```

The class also has a member vector `std::vector<int> myVector`. The conundrum is as follows:

When I place the vector *after* the preprocessor block, thusly:

```
#ifdef MyConditionalCompilation

MyObject myObject;
std::string myString;
uint _myInt;

#endif

std::vector<int> myVector
```

The vector's address gets ... lost?  Moved? during runtime. I can stop at a breakpoint and see members of the vector, as well as its address via `&myVector`, in certain places of my code, but later during execution the vector has lost its memory address and the objects in the vector are gone.

When I move the vector *above* the preprocessor block, thusly:

```
std::vector<int> myVector

#ifdef MyConditionalCompilation

MyObject myObject;
std::string myString;
uint _myInt;

#endif
```

I do not experience the same issue. The vector, its address, and the values I've pushed into it are consistent across runtime.

What on earth is going on here?

For clarity, `MyConditionalCompilation` is true, so the code block is included in the class when it's compiled.

EDIT:  For additional clarity, I've changed the conditional compilation as follows:

```
#define MyConditionalCompilation
#ifdef MyConditionalCompilation

MyObject myObject;
std::string myString;
uint _myInt;

#endif
```

So the code block is absolutely included in both of the test cases described above. I've also verified that the instance of the object is the same in example 1, where the vector "vanishes" at runtime.

Comment: "Gone" is a pretty weird explanation. Does your application behave in a different way? Does it crash?

Comment: At a guess.... You're probably compiling some parts of the code with `MyConditionalCompilation` defined, and other parts with it not defined.  Leading to weird behavior.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know how else to describe it.  As I said, the debugger can't access the memory at `&myVector`, despite being able to do so previously during the execution of the code. @Eljay, I'm not. I can see the variables defined inside the conditional compilation in all cases.

Comment: Can you give us enough code to replicate the problem? Remove any code not needed to replicate the problem and confirm that the problem can be replicated with just the code you've given us. Most likely, the issue is in code not shown.

Comment: I'll try to work something up, good idea David

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your class defined in a header, perhaps? In this case make sure every file that `#include`s it has `MyConditionalCompilation` set with the same value as its implementation, because in C and C++ each `.cpp`/`.cc` file is compiled as a single, standalone translation unit.

Given that you are conditionally adding fields to `MyClass` its size will change, causing the relative offsets of its member fields to differ.

An instance allocated in one file compiled without `MyConditionalCompilation` will have `myVector` at a different address than one compiled with `MyConditionalCompilation` set to 1, and passing it to code that assumes it has a different layout will most definitely cause a runtime crash.

A common pattern that is used to avoid this issue is to ship alongside your headers a `config.h` header containing the configuration values used to build your library.

Comment: It is defined in a header, but `MyConditionalCompilation` is defined in each case. There is only a single instance of my class, and the two different points where I check the vector (in the first case, the vector behaves as expected; the second case, the vector is "lost") I have confirmed that it's the same instance by checking the address of `this`.

Comment: The fact the pointer is the same is irrelevant - if some code that is trying to access the structure has been compiled without the flag, it will assume it has a different memory layout. Try hardcoding the flag to 1 and check if something changes.

Answer (score 0):

Per the recommendations of mcilloni and David Schwartz, I dug into the problem more exhaustively. The answer was unrelated to the original question, so I'll mark this resolved.